# Static and non-static method or global class object

Tags: forms, static, global, non-static

I'm making a Windows Forms Application in VS2012 C++.
Situation just for example, real project is more complicated:
I have a Form that contains TextBox, Button and Timer.
Button just triggers the timer. Timer just calls function that increments some variable.
I need to display the function's variable that is incremented, in TextBox.

In Form1.h I add code:

```
    public: void Timer_Function(); //function activated by timer Tick
    void Set_Text(String ^str); //function to set TextBox Text
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
             if (timer1->Enabled == false)  timer1->Enabled = true;
             else   timer1->Enabled = false;
         }
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
             Timer_Function();
         }
```

In My_app.cpp code like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include "resource.h"

using namespace test_staticfunc;
[STAThreadAttribute]

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
return 0;
}

void Form1::Timer_Function()
{
Timer_Func();
}

void Form1::Set_Text(String ^str)
{
textBox1->Text = str;
}

void Timer_Func()
{
static int I=0;
I++;

Form1::Set_Text(I.ToString());
}
```

Function Timer_Func() is specified in "resource.h" like this:

```
void Timer_Func();
```

I.e. I'm trying to display the current state of inner variable I of Timer_Func() by passing it to a Form1 public method Set_Text().
So. The error here is that Set_Text() is not a static method.
I tried to make it static, but got an error "С2227: The operand to the left of "->Text" is not a pointer to a class, structure, or union." How to get it right? In that case a static method is trying to implement a non-static method, right?

Or another way: to make an instance of Form1 - instead of

```
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
```

insert code

```
Form1 ^My_form = gcnew Form1();
Application::Run(My_form);
```

And use Set_Text as non-static method for class instance My_form.
But My_form is available only in main()! I couldn't make My_form anywhere else. Is there way to make it global or something?

May be there are other ways to solve this problem?

Help, please! I've already searched several forums for answer but didn't find the answer. More precisely non of them suited.
P.S. Sorry for my bad english! ^_^